# Converting a word into set of bytes in Z3

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I'm running the following test in Z3/Python:

```
def test_converting_word_into_byte_array():
    bytes_in_word = 4
    word_size = 8 * bytes_in_word
    word = BitVec('word', word_size)
    word_in_bytes = Array('bytes(word)', BitVecSort(word_size), BitVecSort(8))
    read = BitVec('read', word_size)
    pointer = BitVecVal(0, word_size)
    answer_array = Array('final(word)', BitVecSort(word_size), BitVecSort(8))

    solver = Solver()
    solver.add(word == BitVecVal(2, word_size))
    for byte in range(bytes_in_word):
        solver.add(Select(word_in_bytes, byte) == Extract(word_size - 1 - 8 * byte, word_size - 1 - 7 - 8 * byte, word))
    new_array = Lambda([read],
        If(
            And(ULE(pointer, read), ULE(read, pointer + bytes_in_word - 1)),
            Select(word_in_bytes, read - pointer),
            Select(K(BitVecSort(word_size), BitVecVal(0, 8)), read)))
    solver.add(answer_array == new_array)

    assert str(solver.check()) == "sat"
    print(solver.model())
```

While the solution is satisfactory, ultimately the solver model seems wrong:

```
[final(word) = Lambda(k!0, 2),
 bytes(word) = Lambda(k!0, If(k!0 == 3, 2, 0)),
 word = 2]
```

**Question**

Why is `final(word)` taking on the value of `2` when it should be equivalent to `bytes(word)` due to how the `If` condition is set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using arrays as lambdas in your program. Lambda's are *not* part of the official SMTLib language, (http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf), so it's hard to exactly say if this should be allowed and what the consequences would be. But, as you found out, this seems to be a supported z3 extension, and you have found a bug!

Please report this at their issues site: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues.

NB. The Python encoding is really conflating the issue and making it really hard to read. Here's what I was able to create as a much simpler to read SMTLib benchmark:

```
(set-logic ALL)

(declare-fun inp () (Array Int Int))
(declare-fun out () (Array Int Int))

(assert (= (select inp 0) 0))
(assert (= (select inp 1) 0))
(assert (= (select inp 2) 1))

(assert (= out (lambda ((i Int))
                       (ite (and (<= 0 i) (<= i 2))
                            (select inp i)
                            0))))

(check-sat)

(get-value ((select inp 0)))
(get-value ((select inp 1)))
(get-value ((select inp 2)))
(get-value ((select out 0)))
(get-value ((select out 1)))
(get-value ((select out 2)))
```

For this, z3 reports:

```
sat
(((select inp 0) 0))
(((select inp 1) 0))
(((select inp 2) 1))
(((select out 0) 2))
(((select out 1) 2))
(((select out 2) 2))
```

But clearly, we're expecting equivalence in the range 0-2. I'd strongly recommend you report this SMTLib version of the problem instead of the original Python.

NB. This mixing of lambda's and arrays is definitely a Z3 extension. For instance, this is what CVC4 says on the benchmark:

```
(error "Subexpressions must have a common base type:
Equation: (= out (lambda ((i Int)) (ite (and (<= 0 i) (<= i 2)) (select inp i) 0)))
Type 1: (Array Int Int)
Type 2: (-> Int Int)
")
```

So, you're using an extension that is z3-specific. While that's not a bad thing, it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate response. This is completely valid syntax according to: https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html.

The following example was listed:

```
m, m1 = Array('m', Z, Z), Array('m1', Z, Z)
def memset(lo,hi,y,m):
    return Lambda([x], If(And(lo <= x, x <= hi), y, Select(m, x)))
solve([m1 == memset(1, 700, z, m), Select(m1, 6) != z])
Lambda
```

Comment: I'd like to accept your answer, but the current one needs some corrections. It seems that model generation doesn't work for lambda expressions, but simple satisfiability does.

Comment: Cool. Apparently, this is a z3 extension that is still being worked out. I've updated my answer to reflect that, and also put in a note about the error message CVC4 issues.